# URL Rewriting not working?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

im new here.

Im trying to rewrite some urls on my site only for some reason no matter what I  try I cannot get them to work!

My directory on my server has the following...

index.php

user-profile.php

.htaccess

On my index.php there is a number of users that all have a view more details button that links through to user-profiles and posts an ID using GET method as such...

http://mysite.com/user-profile.php?userID=2&firstName=Martin&lastName=FAM

However Id like to format them as so...

http://mysite.com/people/2/Martin/FAM

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /user-profile.php?userID=$1&firstName=$2&lastName=$3 [L]
```

Can anybody give me some reason as too why this isnt working?

Comment: the module 'mod_rewrite' is enabled?

Comment: Hang on, is this in the root, or the `people` directory?

Comment: This sounds naive, but there isnt a people directory on my server, I thought htaccess just made it look like there was?

Answer (score 1):

The regex should be

```
^people/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have this option set in your document root directory in Apache's httpd.conf file:

```
AllowOverride All
```